# how to create file programmatically only login users download it

Tags: files

I want to create file programmatically ,I want only authenticated user can download it and direct access return  403 to them.
I search and saw [How Can I Make File Downloads Available Only to Authenticated Users?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/59453/how-can-i-make-file-downloads-available-only-to-authenticated-users) but my files not field files(not record in file table) and programmatically I created them with:

```
    $temp1=variable_get('file_public_path').'/export';
      if(!file_prepare_directory($temp1,FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY)){
          drupal_set_message(t('Problem in write file in directory'),'error');
          return;
      }
    $filename='Export-giftcard-'.time().'.csv';
        $filepath=$temp1.'/'.$filename;
    //    $filepath='sites\\defauls\\files\\Export-giftcard-.csv';
        $df = fopen($filepath, 'w');
        if(!$df){
            drupal_set_message(t('Can not write file in').$filepath,'error');
            return;
        }
        fputcsv($df,array('code','credit'));
   fclose($df);
    $path = file_create_url($filepath);
    drupal_set_message(t('Export done. ') . '<a href="' . $path . '">' . t('Download export file') . '</a>');
```

after `rooby` answer I update my question

I set private file system to `system/files/export` and  in my code use it 
`$temp1 = variable_get('file_private_path');`
also I implement `hook_file_download`

```
function mymodule_file_download($uri) {
  // Check if the file is controlled by the current module.
  if (!file_prepare_directory($uri)) {
    $uri = FALSE;
  }
// I will put my conditions later
      $info = image_get_info($uri);
      return array('Content-Type' => $info['mime_type']);
}
```

but when I try to click on link to download file return **Forbidden** to me.I think `mymodule_file_download` not run when I try to access `system/files/export/myfile.csv`

Comment: If you don't want to use file management provided by Drupal, with it's private file system, then it is not really a Drupal question.

Comment: @Mołot , Is it right if I I create it in private file system direct access to it return 403?

Comment: I honestly don't understand the comment above.

Comment: I said If I create a file in private file system ,is it accessible  directly?

Comment: @Mołot I create file in private file system programmatically, but when I want download it ,it return me 403,Forbidden .

Comment: Your private file system path will be something like sites/default/files/private (a directory on your server). The path system/files is a drupal website url, not a path on the file system, and is only used to create hyperlinks to the files that are in the private files directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the private file system instead of the public file system.
The private file system restricts direct access to files.

Then you link to the files like: system/files/filename.ext.
Then when someone clicks one of those links it calls drupal core's [file_download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!file.inc/function/file_download/7) function, which in turn invokes [hook_file_download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7).

Drupal core implements hook_file_download() in the file module as [file_file_download()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/file_file_download/7), which handles these private files to allow users with the appropriate access permissions to download the file.

However file_file_download() won't work out of the box with non drupal field files (like your custom files appear to be), it only works for files attached to drupal fields.

So you will also have to implement your own version of hook_file_download() to handle your particular files.

One way to single out your files and avoid massing with the files that file_file_download() already handles is to put your custom files in a sub-directory of the private files directory that is not used by any other files, then in your hook_file_download() you check for that directory in the file path, return headers if the file is in the right directory and the user has the correct permissions, otherwise, if the user doesn't have perms return -1 and if the file is outside of your special sub-directory just return null to ignore the file and let drupal handle it as normal.

To implement hook_file_download() you have to create a custom drupal module that implements the hook like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_file_download().
 */
function YOURMODULENAME_file_download($uri, $field_type = 'file') {
  // Your code goes here.
}
```

See file_file_download() as an example.

For more information see:
https://drupal.org/node/292
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!module.inc/group/hooks/7

**Note:**
Your private file system path will be something like sites/default/files/private (a directory on your server). The path system/files is a drupal website url, not a path on the file system, and is only used to create hyperlinks to the files that are in the private files directory.

So if you set your private file system path to sites/default/files/private, a hyperlink on your site that points to /system/files/export/filename.txt will open the file on your web server at /sites/default/files/export/filename.txt.

Comment: I understand your theory,but how can I implement it in form sumbmit, I want download file after form submit,

Comment: you mean I implement hook_file_download and in sumbit of my form do something like this ?   `insumbit{ return mymodule_file_download($path); }` ?

Comment: The hook_file_download() handles your access control to your custom file. The download code can be just like you already have except you are saving the file to the private file system instead of the public one and the link to the file that you are creating links to /system/files/filepath.ext instead of /sites/default/files/private/filepath.ext

Comment: When a user downloads a file from system/files/... drupal proccesses it as a private file and then runs hook_file_download() to determine the access control for the file instead of just directly serving the file as it would for a public file.

Comment: I dont understand how can this hook engaged to run? should I call it in my form_submit?

Comment: No, you don't call the hook. Anyone who accesses a file with a file name starting with /system/files/ will cause drupal to run the hook. Then in the hook you check access and return access denied or the file headers if they are allowed to access the file. - I suggest you read the docs on the functions and hooks I linked and also the docs on drupal hooks that I linked to help understand the process more fully. Also see file_menu() for where the system/files path is defined.

Comment: If I set private message to something like /defaults/myprivate .... , does the hook triggered or only triggered when set private path to system/files/.. ?

Comment: I update the question .

Answer (score 2):

Create a private file field as you would if they were regular private files.

Hook in to the file download function: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7

Let Drupal handle permissions,  create your file dynamically.

Comment: @zhilevan   that error suggests that you need to learn how to properly hook in to drupal functions...  and is beyond the scope of this question (and this forum).  Read the documentation at drupal.org,  it will tell you how to properly hook.